# Reduce the amount of "Handles" I use?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling

How can I shorten this down (like into one generic handler/event etc):

```
Private Sub Picturebox_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles a1.Click, a2.Click, a3.Click, a4.Click, a5.Click, b1.Click, b2.Click,
          b3.Click, b4.Click, b5.Click, c1.Click, c2.Click, c3.Click, c4.Click,
          c5.Click, d1.Click, d2.Click, d3.Click, d4.Click, d5.Click, e1.Click,
          e2.Click, e3.Click, e4.Click, e5.Click, f1.Click, f2.Click, f3.Click,
          f4.Click, f5.Click, g1.Click, g2.Click, g3.Click, g4.Click, g5.Click,
          h1.Click, h2.Click, h3.Click, h4.Click, h5.Click, i1.Click, i2.Click,
          i3.Click, i4.Click, i5.Click, j1.Click, j2.Click, j3.Click, j4.Click,
          j5.Click
```

Each of those "Clicks" are for 50 picture boxes, and I'm planning on adding another 50 at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of declaring the click event explicitly on the control in the designer, just loop through all the picture box controls in the form, like this:

```
For Each theControl As Control In Form1.Controls
    If theControl.GetType Is GetType(PictureBox) Then
        Dim thePictureBox As PictureBox = CType(theControl, PictureBox)

        ' Route the click event of this picture box to your single handler
        AddHandler thePictureBox.Click, AddressOf Me.thePictureBox_Click
    End If
Next
```

Now you need to implement the actual handler, like this:

```
Private Sub thePictureBox_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Cast the sender here to a picture box object
    ' and do whatever you need to do when a picture box is clicked here
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, and was easy to modify and adjust for use with a list.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on "theControl", use quick-watch, and find a property that you can use to write your exclude logic.

Comment: @WallaceBreen - great, glad it helped, feel free to up-vote the answer when you can. :-)

Comment: I would do `For Each pb In Form1.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)`. No need for extra checking and casting inside your for-each loop. Also see: [MSDN `Control.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) and [MSDN `Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can asign the event handler to the list of images like this in a cycle holding all the images you need.

```
AddHandler b2.Click, AddressOf Picturebox_Click
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst Karl is correct his for each loop won't find any picture boxes you may have within containers placed on your form.

Try the following which should, and you can of course extend the logic to apply to other controls:

```
  Dim ctrl As Control = Me

     Do
        ctrl = GetNextControl(ctrl, True)

        If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then _

            Select Case ctrl.GetType.ToString
                Case "System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox"
                    AddHandler ctrl.click, AddressOf myCustomButtonClick
                Case Else
                    Exit Select
            End Select
        End If
     Loop Until ctrl Is Nothing
```